# Program is not running don't know why?

Tags: c++, arrays, character

I wrote this code just to find the size of the largest word in the sentence, which is to be provided by the user. I used array do the question.
But the code doesn't run it just stops in the middle, I don't know what is the problem that is causing the code to not run.
I am not able to figure out the problem.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
    
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cin.ignore();
    char a[n+1];
    cin.getline(a,n);
    cin.ignore();
    
    int i=0;
    int currLen=0,maxLen=0;
    
    while(true){
       if(a[i]==' ' || a[i]=='\0'){
          if(currLen>maxLen){
              maxLen=currLen;
          }
              currLen=0;
       }
       else{
           currLen++;
           if(a[i]=='\0'){
               break;
           }
           i++;
       }
            
   }
   cout<<maxLen<<endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i` does not increment when the `if` block is entered - only in `else`. This will result in an "infinite" loop.

Comment: `char a[n+1];` is illegal in standard C++ (without compiler extensions) since the value of `n` needs to be known at compile time, not run time.

Comment: Also, the `break` is set up to hit in the `else`, but the `else` is not entered when `a[i]=='\0'`

Comment: Must read: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Try `char a[n+1]={0};`

Comment: @Odedy:  Variable Length Arrays are not valid in *standard C++*.  Prefer to use `std::vector` or use dynamic memory allocation for arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I changed the logic of your program a bit. As far as I understand in the beginning you enter the number of words in the sentence for further manipulation with memory allocation. I will say that for allocating an unknown amount of memory it is better to use dynamic allocation. Example:

```
char* a;
a = new char[n + 1];
```

So, I rewrote the program, I made it so that the number of words is determined automatically, and the end of the sentence will be indicated by a dot.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char sentence[256];
    char stop_char = 'X';
    cin.getline(sentence, 256, '.');
    int len = 0;
    int max_len = 0;
    int i = 0;
    bool stop = false;

    while (stop == false)
    {
        stop_char = sentence[i];
        if (sentence[i] != ' ' && sentence[i] != 0 && sentence[i] != ',')
            len++;
        else
        {
            if (len > max_len)
            {
                max_len = len;
                len = 0;
            }
            if (sentence[i] == 0)
            {
                cout << max_len << endl;
                stop = true;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And so, we enter a sentence like "One, two, three and smth else", the program starts scrolling, if we get a comma, space, or zero terminator, we go to compare the length with the maximum. When we get a zero terminator, the program exits the loop and terminates. I would also like to tell you that it is better not to use "break".